# glmmLasso warnings variable selection for mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-models

I used glmmLasso() to run a variable selection on linear mixed model with random subject effect.

y = post-treatment response at time 1 or 2

y0 = baseline response

sex = male / female

group = control / treatment

time = categorized time 1 or 2

I ran this code and got eight warnings, all the same:

```
glmmLasso(y ~ y0 + age +sex + group + time, rnd=(ID=~1), lambda=10, data)
```

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (class(InvFisher2) == "try-error") InvFisher2 <- try(solve(F_gross),  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (class(InvFisher2) == "try-error") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (class(InvFisher2) == "try-error") InvFisher2 <- try(solve(F_gross),  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (class(InvFisher2) == "try-error") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (class(InvFisher2) == "try-error") InvFisher2 <- try(solve(F_gross),  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (class(InvFisher2) == "try-error") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
7: In if (class(InvFisher2) == "try-error") InvFisher2 <- try(solve(F_gross),  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
8: In if (class(InvFisher2) == "try-error") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Output:

```
Fixed Effects:

Coefficients:
                    Estimate StdErr z.value p.value
(Intercept)           5.1461     NA      NA      NA
y0                    0.0000     NA      NA      NA
Age                   0.0000     NA      NA      NA
SexFemale             0.0000     NA      NA      NA
group                 0.0000     NA      NA      NA
time2                 0.0000     NA      NA      NA

Random Effects:

StdDev:
          ID
ID 0.2665597
```

How to fix it?

Attempted approaches:

1. treat categorical variables as binary factors, (or 0 vs 1)
2. different lambdas from 1 to 100

I used the same command for another continuous response and got the exact same warnings 42 times!

I dont know how to include data here and due to confidentiality, I only included a subset as pictures. There are total 50 subjects, each has max 2 responses (plus 1 baseline). Only 5 people are females.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post your data using dput()?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Could you figure it out somehow? Why does it display so many NAs in the output summary table SD and p.values?

Comment: No i didnt figure it out.